# azure notification hub how to send tag array

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub

i am want to send a bunch of notification to users in rapidly changing groups.
hence  the broadcast model doesnt work as the updating of registration tags will be excessive.

so i figured i can just send to a 'group of tag'. where each tag is a single user.

but it seems i am limited to using an 20 tags in an OR expression.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx

Q1. is there any other mechanism to send an array of tags?

thanks

-lp

Answer (score 0):

Right NH does not have such mechanism. Customers typically perform multiple send calls to reach the goal you are talking about.

NH team is constantly adding new features, so situation may change shortly.